# What are these plastic pieces on my water pipes for?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, copper-pipe

I have these plastic pieces around my copper water pipes that run under the stairs. What are these black and white plastic pieces for? They seem to serve no purpose. Thank you.

[image: Picture of water pipes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Christmas decoration holders/hangers.

Look like they are to hold pipes to joists/walls.

Probably put on and never used or were used at one time but removed for painting/repair of wall and forgot to be put back.

Comment: They are pipe hangers.

Comment: Looks like they are intended to be attached to the wall where the pipes go through the wall to hold the pipes secure there, but they are on the pipe backwards, with the flat-to-wall side facing out instead of in.

Comment: Slide the hanger to the other end of the exposed pipe, @Armand, and presto-changeo they're installed correctly! :D